# Is there a Python function for making a graph of the percentages of each category of a categorical feature in each cluster?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to make a graph that looks like

[image: this]

I tried using this to make a table but the only issue is that it formats it as two sets of rows instead of two columns.

```
combinedDf.groupby(['Cluster Label'])['Diagnosis'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```

I'm supposed to do this for all the features in my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to plotly library. You can make a lot of cool graphs using this lab.

I believe that I found an easy way to solve your issue.

Given a dataframe look like this :

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips() #this is a dataframe example provide by plotly for us to exercice

print(df)

>>> output:
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
0         16.99  1.01  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     2
1         10.34  1.66    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
2         21.01  3.50    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
3         23.68  3.31    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2
4         24.59  3.61  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     4
..          ...   ...     ...    ...   ...     ...   ...
239       29.03  5.92    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     3
240       27.18  2.00  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
241       22.67  2.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
242       17.82  1.75    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     2
243       18.78  3.00  Female     No  Thur  Dinner     2
```

You can plot a graph like this :

[image: Graph]

With a simple code :

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x="sex", y="total_bill", color="smoker", barmode="group", histfunc="sum")
fig.show()
```

In your case, you figure code line will like like:

fig = px.histogram(df, x="Diagnosis", y="Percentage", color="Show", barmode="group", histfunc="sum")

Sorry, but I don't fully understand you request, so I can't help you more. If you want to learn more about the graph I displayed, i strongly recommend you to take a look to this : https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/